LWC Nested in Aura Component, Launched From Global Action - Not Loading when Relaunched
I am working on an Aura Component, which contains an LWC. The reason that I've used an Aura component to contain the LWC is because I need to use it in a Global Action, and based on my research, it seems that global actions aren't visible unless used with an Aura component (despite it being an option to select an LWC).
The Aura component looks like this:

<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId">

<aura:html tag="style">
        .slds-modal__container{
        height : auto;
        
        }
        .modal-body{
        height : auto !important;
        max-height: auto !important;
        }
    </aura:html> 

    <c:workProRequestCreationForm aura:id="workProRequestCreationForm" recordId="{!v.recordId}" onclose="{!c.handleClose}">
    </c:workProRequestCreationForm>
</aura:component>

The Javascript controller contains a single 'on close' method:
({
    handleClose : function(component,event){ 
        $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire(); 
    }
})

I've found that when I launch the global action, for example from a Contact page, the component works as expected, and displays the LWC properly. However, if I then close the quick action (either via the 'X' or the cancel button in my LWC) and relaunch it, the component is entirely blank. In order to display the component properly again, I need to fully refresh the page and click the button again.
You can see in the below images that I've added some 'test' text - this is on the Aura component, not the LWC. The fact that this text still appears when launched the second time implies to me that there's specifically an issue with how the LWC is being rendered; potentially it's being destroyed and not being recreated when the quick action is reopened.
How the component looks when launching initially:

Then, I close this and press the quick action again to relaunch it:

I haven't provided any of the code of the LWC, only because that component is still working fine; it's just the wrapper Aura component that has the issue.
Thanks!

I've tried to reproduce this, but - based on your Aura - a minimalistic LWC displaying "Hello World" reappears after being closed and reopened. (I haven't configured the js-meta.xml of the LWC.) If the LWC fires a close event (I added a button), it works too. Could you please add relevant code of your LWC to your question, so one can reproduce the problem? Have you had a look at the Chrome console, if any Javascript errors surface, possibly?
